# What connector is this? (Inside a wifi modem)

Tags: connector, antenna, wireless, modem, network-interface

I was about to attach an antenna to my 4g modem and thus trying to identify which connector is there on my modem board and i found this connector (4 of them, 2 for 4g and 2 for wifi).

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

I tried connecting u.fl female pigtail to it and it does not work. I suspect it is a female ipex, but i know you guys know better. Pls tell me.

Pls make use of the miniSIM card nearby for size reference, thank you.

Comment: Its a "Microwave coaxial connector". Have a look here: https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/connector/cableconnector  Those are from Murata, other manufacturers also make them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a coax receptacle with an internal N/C switch.

The N/C switch brings a 50Ohm connection between the onboard/default (e.g. PCB trace type) antenna and the RF transceiver (Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, 2G/3G/4G or whatever). When an external antenna is plugged into the receptacle, the default antenna gets disconnected from the transceiver. It also enables a connection to measurement equipment (e.g. spectrum analyzer) to measure the transmit/receive power.

Murata's SWF series and Hirose's MS-156C series are quite popular.

Comment: wow thank you very much, this realy clearly solved my question.

Comment: @yuda then you can accept my answer by clicking the tick button so that the question does not remain open.